# awkakeFromNib,initWithCoder,initWithFrame not being called

Tags: ios, uitableview

none of awakeFromNib,initWithFrame,initWithCoder are being called in custom TableViewCell, when a cell is dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. 
Note that the cell is registered in code like,
  [self.tableView registerClass:[RGTableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"1"];
. An RGTableViewCell is being dequeued but none of the initialization methods that I mentioned are called. I was hoping to do some setup in one of those methods.

Thanks for any hints, 
Cheers

Comment: Where you create RGTableViewCell (code, xib, storyboard)?

Comment: In principle I don't have to create it, that's the whole point of registering it with the tableView. And since i'm registering a class it should be going through the class's initWithFrame,key word should.

Comment: You must have created a class right. A .m and .h file for your cell, where you have implement these 3 methods. That is what @LDNZh is asking

Comment: If its not nib then try implementing init method. This will get called.

Comment: Do you use xib file for your cell?

Comment: no i do not use nibs.

Comment: try call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` instead of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier `

Comment: I've already tried that, with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designated initializer for a UITableViewCell is initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:, as is stated in the class reference. If you are not using a xib or storyboard to create your cell, that's the initializer that should be called.

Comment: Golden, Thank you sir. I knew there had to be an different default initializer but had a hard time finding which one. Going to, https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html and searching "default initializer" didn't yeild any results. Could you enlighten us how you go about finding the default initializers ? Thanks

Comment: @user103412, the first place you should always go is the class reference.  There is only one initializer listed in the UITableViewCell class reference, and it states in the discussion that it is the designated initializer.

Answer (score 0):

awakeFromNib and initWithCoder are typically only called when the XIB loader builds the view. Since you've said that you're using a custom cell class, I assume that the class is creating all the subviews.  If that is the case then I believe that the standard init method will get called on your custom UITableViewCell class.

Comment: well, technically  initWithFrame is the default initializer for UIView and hence i did set a break point at that location only to find out that it wasn't breaking there. That's why i got confused and started  breaking in awkakeFromNib and initWithCoder. Also, note that it's still not breaking in init.